# Как сделать кнопку из PNG файла (изображение внутри вопроса) на html/css или js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

[image]

Кнопка должна быть из этого png изображения, прозрачные элементы должный быть прозрачными соответственно

Comment: <button><img src="url image" alt=""></button>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Два варианта на выбор

```css
.use-1 {
  background: red;
}

.use-1 button {
  background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/f96BW.png') no-repeat;
  width: 97px;
  height: 97px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 0;
}

.use-2 {
  background: blue;
}

.use-2 button {
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 0;
}


button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="use-1">
<button></button>
</div>

<div class="use-2">
<button><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/f96BW.png" alt=""></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunc() {
  //ACTIONS
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/f96BW.png" onclick="myFunc()">
```